# Is it possible to disable merging on master at a given date on TFS

Tags: tfs

I have a special need. In my organization we have a specific workflow, and it would be great to disable merging on master one day before we pass everything in production, and after everything is passed on production we can allow merging again.

We use Team Foundation Server. Are there any settings that would allow us to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no settings that will lock a branch on a specific date, but you could do so manually. You could use branch security to make the branch read-only for the day, or you could use branch policies to set a policy that cannot pass. The following sets the required viewers to be more members than are in your team...

The following may be slightly different based on the version of TFS that you are working with;

1. Go to **Code | Branches** for your repository
2. Hover over the master branch until you see the three dots **...** and click on them.

[image: Master Branch Policies]

3. Click on **Branch Policies**
4. Click on **Protect this branch**
5. Click on **Require a minimum number of reviewers**
6. Set the minimum number of reviewers to a number higher than are on your team. 10 is the max.

[image: Minimum Reviewers]

7. After the release, set it back.

You could automate this in Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS) or possibly in newer versions of TFS on-premise (I only have access to the initial release of TFS 2017), by creating an external service that returns false on specific days and setting it as required to merge to master. Here is a [tutorial on creating a status server with Node.Js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server?view=vsts).

[image: Approval from external service]

Comment: Thank you for the quick and clean response !